# DAT not saving entire object JAVA

Tags: java, io, binary

Hey im trying to save an object to a .dat. The object im trying to save is a Student with the parameters of Student[usernmae, password, name, idnum, major, gpa]. When i make a new object all the parameters are filled in, and when i save it its all filled in. But when ever i load in the object all it loads is the username and password. Its like it doesnt even save the rest of it. Anyone have any fixes?

Loader class:

```
public static void loader()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
 try {
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("students.dat");
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
 //a loop to continue reading the next line 
 //of a binary file for the next student
 while(true){
   try {
    stud = ois.readObject();

  }catch(EOFException e){
    break;
  }  
}
  student = (Student) stud;
  System.out.println(student);
  studentBag.add(student);
  ois.close();
  fis.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found");
}
}
```

Saver Class:

```
public static void saver(Student student)throws IOException{
try {
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("students.dat");
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
 oos.writeObject(student);
 System.out.println(student.toString());
 oos.flush();
 oos.reset();
 oos.close();
 fos.close();
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 System.out.println("File not found");
}
}
```

And yes my student object is serializeable.. `  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

When i print out the student from the file this is the output:

Student [name=null, userName=111, password=111, majorID=null, gpa=0.0]

`

Comment: Can you show your student class?

Comment: I have it fixed now, what ended up happeneing is that when i saved the information the TextAreas where all messed up so they werent saving right.